# In C # how to pass string.empty in a list of string

Tags: c#, string, list, arraylist

i have a list of string

```
Emails = new List<string>() { "R.Dun@domain.co.nz", "S.Dun@domain.co.nz" }
```

now i want to pass `string.empty` to first value of list

something like

```
policy.Emails = new List<string>(){string.Empty};
```

how to put a loop for e.g. for each value of list do something.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly set the first element as string.Empty:

```
policy.Emails[0]=string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexof function for finding a string in the list as below,

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>() { "R.Dun@domain.co.nz", "S.Dun@domain.co.nz" };

int fIndex = strList.IndexOf("R.Dun@domain.co.nz");

if(fIndex != -1)
    strList[fIndex] = string.Empty;
```

Or if you want to replace first item with string.Empty then as dasblinkenlight mentioned you can do using the index directly,

```
strList[0] = string.Empty
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend `string.Empty` to an existing list with concat:

```
var emails = new List<string> {"R.Dun@domain.co.nz", "S.Dun@domain.co.nz"};
policy.Emails = new[] {string.Empty}.Concat(emails).ToList();
```

Now `policy.Emails` looks like this:

```
{"", "R.Dun@domain.co.nz", "S.Dun@domain.co.nz"}
```

If you would like to replace the first item, use `Skip(1)` before concatenating:

```
policy.Emails = new[] {string.Empty}.Concat(emails.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

To generalize, replacing the initial `n` values with empty strings would look like this:

```
policy.Emails = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 1).Concat(emails.Skip(n)).ToList();
```

**Note:** It goes without saying that if you do not mind modifying the list in place, the simplest solution is to do

```
emails[0] = string.Empty;
```

Comment: thanks, how can i replace R.Dun@doman.co.nz with a empty string ?

Comment: @shab Do you want to replace `"R.Dun@domain.co.nz"` because it is the first item on the list?

Comment: yes i want to replace the first item with an empty string

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add an empty string at the beginning of a list you could do:

```
emails.Insert(0, string.Empty);
```